# Having trouble with callback and promise handling while scraping parallel

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, callback, promise, puppeteer

I am trying to use parallel scraping with puppeteer js to get lots of data at the same time. Currently my code opens 5 chromium instances and searches for something on the website. Now everytime I start I get a "callback is not a function error" and for every instance a promise handling error.

My scraper:

```
module.exports = async function scrape(article, dealer, callback) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage(); //open new page
  await page.setUserAgent(
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
  );
  await page.goto(dealer);

  //Site specific code
  await page.type(".Search-bar-text-input", article);
  await page.click(".Embedded-search-button");

  //Get data
  try {
    await page.waitFor(".BuyingOptions-total-price", { timeout: 3000 });
    price = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let price = document.querySelector(".BuyingOptions-total-price")
        .innerText;
      console.log(price);
      return price;
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error finding price");
    console.log(err);
    price = "";
  }
  browser.close();
  Promise.resolve();

  let result = {
    price: price
  };

  callback("Error", result);
};
```

my app.js where I have the parallel function:

```
artikel.getData(async function() {
  for (let article of arrayOfArticles) {
    requests.push(() => scrape(article, dealer));
  }

  console.log(requests);
  async.parallel(requests, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: `scrape(article, dealer)`, callback isn't passed to `scrape` method. Hence your `callback` invocation in last line of `scrape` method fails. That's the error.

Comment: oh I didnt see that , now I get "callback is not defined" though

Comment: any idea @yaswanth ?

Comment: can you post the updated code?

Comment: I just added callback in `scrape(article, dealer, callback) as you suggested`

Comment: What is `callback`? Could you update the code to show both its value and how you call `scrape` now?

Comment: @AlexJones, the error is what it says! `callback` is not defined. Where are you initialiizing you `callback` variable?